# DsGetDomainControllerInfo returns a "Pointer to a pointer variable that receives an array"? I don't get it

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, pointers

Most of my experience is with C#...so I'm still getting used to C++.

I'm trying to call DsGetDomainControllerInfo to get all of the domain controllers in the domain. Here's a link to the MSDN docs for that call:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675987(v=vs.85).aspx

The fourth parameter returns the number of DC's that should be in the array of DS_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO_* structures.

I'm getting the first DS_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO_* in the array, but it throws an unhandled exception on the second. The last argument is a void**...I'm casting to that, but I doubt that's the right thing to do.

Here's my code:

```
PDOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO logonDomainController;
DsGetDcName(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &logonDomainController);
wstring domCon = logonDomainController->DomainControllerName;
wstring domNam = logonDomainController->DomainName;
HANDLE domHan;
DsBindWithCred(domCon.c_str(), domNam.c_str(), NULL, &domHan);
DWORD count = 0;
DS_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO_3 *dci[100] = { NULL };
DsGetDomainControllerInfo(domHan, domNam.c_str(), 3, &count, (void**)dci);

for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    wcout << dci[i]->DnsHostName << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation as: you have to declare `DS_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO_3 *dci;` and pass its address as `(VOID**) &dci` (in the sense of a result/"out" parameter), so `dci` can be assigned the base address of the ..INFO_3 array by the callee. You can still access the elements of the array with `dci[i]`.

I think it becomes clearer when reading the linked documentation for the `DsFreeDomainControllerInfo` function (which takes the same pointer as "in" parameter).